# Android: Compose did not get idle after 4303627 attempts in 60 SECONDS. Roboelectric issue

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose, junit5

I am getting the below error when there is an update in the UI. For example showing a Lottie animation while fetching data from API or updating the list when filter is applied.

```
Compose did not get idle after 4303627 attempts in 60 SECONDS. Please check your measure/layout lambdas, they may be causing an infinite composition loop. Or set Espresso's master idling policy if you require a longer timeout. The following Idle Conditions failed .
androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Compose did not get idle after 4303627 attempts in 60 SECONDS. Please check your measure/layout lambdas, they may be causing an infinite composition loop. Or set Espresso's master idling policy if you require a longer timeout. The following Idle Conditions failed .
    at androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException.create(AppNotIdleException.java:11)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.RobolectricIdlingStrategy$runUntilIdle$1.invoke(RobolectricIdlingStrategy.android.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.RobolectricIdlingStrategy$runUntilIdle$1.invoke(RobolectricIdlingStrategy.android.kt:48)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidSynchronization_androidKt.runOnUiThread(AndroidSynchronization.android.kt:33)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.RobolectricIdlingStrategy.runUntilIdle(RobolectricIdlingStrategy.android.kt:48)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:336)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidTestOwner.getRoots(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:529)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.TestContext.getAllSemanticsNodes$ui_test_release(TestOwner.kt:85)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.fetchSemanticsNodes$ui_test_release(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:62)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.fetchOneOrDie(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:128)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.fetchSemanticsNode(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:79)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidAssertions_androidKt.checkIsDisplayed(AndroidAssertions.android.kt:29)
```

This occurs only while running all the test together.

Please let me know if anyone have some suggestion on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue

Comment: for me the problem was the data loading was taking some time, hence added code to wait until data is loaded.